# Destructive interference of electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

[image]

So EM waves can have constructive interference and destructive interference right?

If two strips of EM wave intersect at a point in a destructive manner, would their propagation terminate?

If yes, then how would the momentum and force act on this system?

Comment: @Nickolas Alves But how exactly do they continue to propagates beyond the destructive intersection ？

Comment: E may be zero  but its derivatives not, the magnetic field is also non zero

Comment: @SimonLin jensen's comment is a great way of seeing it. Also, do notice that destructive interference means only that both waves are getting opposite values at that point, but electromagnetism is linear, and hence they will not affect each other. They add up to zero in a point, and that's pretty much it. Also, if you'd like further clarification on an answer, please comment on the answer, not on the question. This makes it easier for future readers to find the relevant discussions

Comment: An up tsunami can come from the east and a down tsunami from the west ..... when they meet they superimpose and voila nothing .... BUT the waves do reemerge and continue on their way!  THE energy and forces being stored in the elasticity of the water.  For the EM field there must be something similar!

Answer (score 2):

> So EM waves can have constructive interference and destructive interference right?

Yes.

> If two strips of EM wave intersect at a point in a destructive manner, would their propagation terminate?

No. Just like with any other wave, they'd interfere destructively at that point, but the interference might be different at other points. One can even get standing electromagnetic waves inside a metal box, such as a microwave oven, for example.

As a fun fact, a do-at-home experiment that one can sometimes find is to remove the rotating plate from the microwave and put some chocolate in it. Since it has standing waves, some pieces of the chocolate will melt really fast, while others will not melt at all (showing the waves are interfering destructively at those points). By measuring the distances of the melted parts, one can find the wavelength. By using the microwave's frequency (often found behind the oven), one can get an estimate for the speed of light. While this (clearly) doesn't have much precision, you can get the order or magnitude correctly by playing with chocolate.

Comment: An up tsunami can come from the east and a down tsunami from the west ..... when they meet they superimpose and voila nothing .... BUT the waves do reemerge and continue on their way! THE energy and forces having being stored in the elasticity of the water. For the EM field there must be something similar!

Comment: @PhysicsDave As jensen mentioned in the comments to the post, you'll have a vanishing electric field, but not a vanishing magnetic field, and so on. Hence, you just switch between electric and magnetic energy.

Comment: An experiment with impinging photons of opposite direction/phase/polarization may not be too hard to set up ...... The Maxwell model would sum to net zero ..... both E and M! The medium is the magic ..... I'm not sure I agree with Jensens M.

Answer (score 1):

There is an essential difference between matter waves and EM waves.

If the excited particles of two waves with opposite amplitudes meet, their kinetic energy is dispersed sideways. Ideally, the wave disappears and the temperature of the medium increases.

For EM waves, no medium is needed. The photons of the EM wave do not interact with each other, they (almost always) pass each other unhindered.

However, we notice interference when two EM waves of opposite amplitudes hit an antenna rod. Then the surface electrons on the rod are moved in opposite directions and the electronics only get noise.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to remember is that using the word *interference* has often caused a conceptual problem about the effect of the meeting of two waves in a region of space.
One wave does not affect the other wave in that each individual wave is oblivious to what the other wave is doing.
What is "observed" is the redirection of energy transfer when two waves travel through the same region of space.
So in some locations no energy is propagated whereas in other regions there is a variable amount of energy propagated but overall there is no net loss of energy propagated.

Your diagram is very limited in that you only are showing what happens at one point is space and neglecting what is happening all around.  I cannot find a ripple tank demonstration video of two source interference in which one views the wave pattern edge on (parallel to the surface of the water) rather that from above or below the ripple tank.  If one does view edge on then the transfer of energy in some regions and none in others can clearly be seen.

Comment: An up tsunami can come from the east and a down tsunami from the west ..... when they meet they superimpose and voila nothing .... BUT the waves do reemerge and continue on their way! THE energy and forces having being stored in the elasticity of the water. For the EM field there must be something similar!